# Google Document AI Labeling Task

Tags: data-science, google-developers-console, cloud-document-ai

Here everyone, I am fairly new google cloud console. I am trying to customize a google document ai model that will learn to extract different sections of document to various data. As you can on the image that it fails to train the model and I have been running the Labeling Task for several days now I have not seen progress. Can you please assist in telling what is the right way to customize google document ia model[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdRNm.png)

I have tried to manually label the different sections of the document, it took me a while so I did around 20 test and training dataset which I think the model to not train then I decided to do the Labeling Task as an alternative to manually labeling the dataset.

Comment: Error
Internal error encountered. This is the error I get when I view the error's details

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments. Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the information about Labeling Tasks for Document AI

- https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/label-documents#labeling-tasks

Labeling Tasks use [Human-in-the-Loop](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/hitl) to have human labelers label documents for training data or production review. You can either set up your own labeling team or apply for access to the [Google-Managed Workforce](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/hitl/google-workforce).

However, it doesn't seem like this is the correct course of action for what you are trying to do, since the labeling has already been completed.
Could you provide more clarification on what you are trying to accomplish with the Custom Document Extractor?

Note: Some of the error messages that are output from Document AI Workbench are not very descriptive (e.g. `Internal Error Occurred`) but the product development team is working to surface more helpful errors when possible.